# Properties and applications of $\phi(X)=a^{T}X$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Are there any interesting properties for the following mapping:
$$
\phi: \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n},\quad k<n
$$
given by: $$\phi(X)=a^{T}X$$ In other words, for a given vector $a$, the mapping basically defines a sequential inner product between $a$ and each column of $X$.

The properties I am looking for are:

> (1) other than being a linear mapping what properties does it have

> (2) What possible applications exist in dimensionality reduction for data mining and machine learning applications?

Side note: I thought about this in trying to reduce number of operations in dynamic programming applications, where I have to loop over all possible combinations of the state vector exhaustively. To resolve this, I replaced the state-vector with a matrix that tries to fit the entire state-space and perform sequential inner product with a vector $a$ (which has a cost-term meaning in my application).

Comment: Some basic properties are implied by the [rank + nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).  Perhaps it would improve your Question to sketch your interest in this mapping.

Comment: I have edited my questions accordingly @hardmath

Comment: I would be inclined to view your construction as choosing $a \in \mathbb R^k$ to form a linear combination of the rows of $X$, each of length $n$.  Of course this sort of thing comes up all the time in linear algebra, and the topic of "dimensionality reduction for data mining" hardly narrows the possibilities.  One would naturally exclude the trivial case $a = 0$ since this erases all information.  It is unclear why one chooses particular (nonzero) $a$, as making the choice uniformly for all $X$ does not leave much room for analysis, and having $a$ depend on $X$ may not be linear.

Comment: If $a$ is not $0$, then $\phi$ is surjective. The null-space of $\phi$ consists of all matrices whose rows corresponding to non-zero entries in $a$ are zero. There is not much more to say for a generic $a$. As for your second question, that is more computer science than mathematics.